# Azure Synapse Serverless to open parquet files with dynamic column lists

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-synapse

I'm getting variable length parquet files dropped onto a Azure Storage Account folder that I'm reading with Azure Synapse. Most of the columns are always sent, however there are multiple columns that instead of sending in a separate message are added in like this:
3 Skills (example 1)

```
EntityId
Name
Profession
Skill_0
Skill_1
Skill_2
```

1 Skill (example 2)

```
EntityId
Name
Profession
Skill_0
```

In example 2 with 1 skill, my process would blow up as it is expecting columns Skill_1 and Skill_2. Is the only option to always have the parquet file sent with every column?

My main question is how to select data from columns that don't always exist in Azure Synapse Serverless? This does not work with example 2 as Skill_1 and Skill_2 do not exist:

```
SELECT EntityId,Name,Profession,Skill_0,Skill_1,Skill_2 FROM
openrowset(BULK 'https://servername.blob.core.windows.net/datalake/Bronze/ServiceBus/Skills/2023-05-26-14-17-11-821.parquet', FORMAT = 'parquet') AS ROWS
```